# Ordenar punteros de lista doblemente enlazada

Tags: c, lista, punteros

Está la siguiente estructura:

```
typedef struct nodo{
    int matricula, edad;
    char nombre[20];
    float peso, altura;
    struct nodo *next, *prev;
} List;
List *first, *buffer, *buffer2;
```

Y para ordenarla, según el miembro, hay funciones (esta es para ordenar por matrícula):

```
void ordenar_matricula(void){
int aux;
char auxc[50];
float auxf;
buffer = first;
while(buffer->next != NULL){
    buffer2 = buffer->next;
    while(buffer2 != NULL){
        if(buffer->matricula > buffer2->matricula){
            aux = buffer2->matricula;
            buffer2->matricula = buffer->matricula;
            buffer->matricula = aux;

            strcpy(auxc,buffer2->nombre);
            strcpy(buffer2->nombre,buffer->nombre);
            strcpy(buffer->nombre,auxc);

            aux = buffer2->edad;
            buffer2->edad = buffer->edad;
            buffer->edad = aux;

            auxf = buffer2->peso;
            buffer2->peso = buffer->peso;
            buffer->peso = auxf;

            auxf = buffer2->altura;
            buffer2->altura = buffer->altura;
            buffer->altura = auxf;
        }
        buffer2 = buffer2->next;
    }
    buffer = buffer->next;
}
imprimir();

return;
}
```

Como pueden ver lo que en realidad hace es intercambiar cada miembro según el orden. Funciona, pero lo que quiero saber es por qué esto no funciona:

```
void ordenar_matricula(void){
List *aux;
buffer = first;
while(buffer->next != NULL){
    buffer2 = buffer->next;
    while(buffer2 != NULL){
        if(buffer->matricula > buffer2->matricula){
            aux = buffer2;
            buffer2 = buffer;
            buffer = aux;
        }
        buffer2 = buffer2->next;
    }
    buffer = buffer->next;
}
imprimir();

return;
}
```

Es decir, por qué no se ordena al tratar de intercambiar directamente los punteros. No creo que sea el método porque había intentado otro pero el programa crasheaba.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

el problema, se encuentra en las tres siguientes líneas:

```
aux = buffer2;
buffer2 = buffer;
buffer = aux;
```

El problema es que estas intercambiendo los punteros, pero no el contenido de las estructura a las que apunta dichos punteros.
Si queres cambiar el contenido de las estructuras que apuntas los punteros, podrias escribir asi:

```
aux = *buffer2;
*buffer2 = *buffer;
*buffer = aux;
```

Donde **aux**, no es un puntero a List, sino una estructura **List**. O sea definirías **aux** de la siguiente manera.

```
List aux;
```

Pero ... acá también surge otro problema, que si bien realmente intercambias el contenido de las estructuras, también estas modificando los punteros **next** y **prev**.

Una solución es "sabiendo" que **next** y **prev** estan al final de la estructura, lo que podrias hacer es usar la función **memcpy**, copiar toda la estructura menos los dos últimos punteros, de la siguiente manera:

```
void ordenar_matricula(void)
{
    List aux;
    buffer = first;
    while(buffer->next != NULL)
    {
        buffer2 = buffer->next;
        while(buffer2 != NULL)
        {
            if(buffer->matricula > buffer2->matricula)
            {
                memcpy(&aux, buffer2, sizeof(List) - sizeof(List*)*2);
                memcpy(buffer2, buffer, sizeof(List) - sizeof(List*)*2);
                memcpy(buffer, &aux, sizeof(List) - sizeof(List*)*2);
            }
            buffer2 = buffer2->next;
        }
        buffer = buffer->next;
    }
    imprimir();
}
```